# Select Primary Key In Inner Join

Tags: sql-server, select, inner-join

I Made An Statement For Select In SQL Server

```
SELECT Oid      AS 'Order ID',
       Eid      AS 'Employee ID',
       Barcode,
       PacksQty AS 'Pack Quantity',
       UnitQty  AS 'Units Quantity',
       Date     AS 'Order Date',
       Price    AS 'Total Price'
FROM   OrderDetails
       INNER JOIN Orders
         ON OrderDetails.Oid = Orders.Oid
```

And The Error In Selecting The Oid And The Error Is "Ambiguous column name 'Oid'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Oid` is ambiguous as it is in both tables. Unlike a natural join (not implemented in SQL Server) you need to specify the table that you want to `SELECT` the value from.

This may seem redundant as your query already specifies `OrderDetails.Oid = Orders.Oid` but the two values can actually be different (e.g. if `OrderDetails.Oid` was `'abc'` and `Orders.Oid` was `'ABC'` and on a case insensitive collation).

You can define a table alias to avoid typing out the whole table name. Example syntax below (making some assumptions about your schema)

```
SELECT O.Oid      AS 'Order ID',
       O.Eid      AS 'Employee ID',
       OD.Barcode,
       OD.PacksQty AS 'Pack Quantity',
       OD.UnitQty  AS 'Units Quantity',
       OD.Date     AS 'Order Date',
       OD.Price    AS 'Total Price'
FROM   OrderDetails OD
       INNER JOIN Orders O
         ON OD.Oid = O.Oid
```